# Django CMS how to blog post

Tags: django, django-cms, djangocms-text-ckeditor

I am learning `Django-CMS` but I am now extremely good at django.

I am not getting how to post through djang-CMS, I have created some pages on Django-cms, just going through menu creation, template, etc.

But I couldn't find any menu or option to post something as like as WordPress has `add post` button.

My question is, should i add new app named

```
blog and configure a with `app hook` or there is a good way to make a blog site?
```

Their documentation are not too good and too old documentation. as a beginner, I confused anything.

I need someone suggestion what i need to do to post with django-CMS? even i can select category etc through django-CMS, how can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

django-cms itself does not provide any blogging tools.

you can embed an existing blog system (zinnia, or djangocms-blog, to name two). when the blog system itself doesnt provide it, you must develop the "glue" between the cms and the blog by yourself, with an so called "app hook", that allows to pull in an existing app under a cms site. that said, have a look at djangocms-blog, for an example glue....as the name implies, it's made for django-cms.